# Compact framework application gets deleted when the battery dies

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, compact-framework, windows-ce, cab

I am developing an application in C# .Net 3.5 Compact framework for a Handheld Computer which runs on Microsoft Windows CE 6.0.
I am able to create the installer and run the application, the hurdle what I am facing right now is, say the battery dies/you perform a Cold Boot on the device (the device is Datalogic Memor X3 http://www.datalogic.com/eng/products/healthcare/mobile-computers/memor-x3-healthcare-pd-814.html#), the application gets deleted, the user will have to re-install the application. I would like to know how to get rid off this problem? Is there something I need to do while building the Setup/Installer? There are other applications in the device which do not get deleted when performed a Cold boot.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most if not all vendors of Windows CE based devices offer a persistent storage area and factory reset / autoinstall procedure.

If the device is clean/cold booted, the 'normal' storage area is reset to factory default. So all custom applications and changes are deleted. When the device boots up, there is a OEM specific autoinstall process. You need to integrate your setup with the autoinstall.

Please see the Datalogic Memor X3 support page and look at the user manual on how to persist your application with this Datalogic device (I would have done that for you, but they require a registration).

UPDATE: see https://www.manualslib.com/manual/850035/Datalogic-Memor-X3.html?page=64#manual and read about Save Session and Save Setup.

At least you can use a SD Card with a special folder (ie 2577 for devices with ARM processor) and a custom autorun.exe inside. This will be executed automatically on every boot.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the root filesystem of a Windows CE devices is RAM-based, using the object store. Mass storage devices are mounted as subfolders. This means that any application that is not installed on a folder connected to a mass-storage device will disappear when RAM contents are erased. In your case this happens when the battery dies because the device never actually turns off, just suspends and resumes.
You should try to install your application on a permanent folder, they should show a different icon in file explorer.